# Responsive Slider Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I'm trying to add a responsive slider to my website and am having a couple of issues.  The biggest is the size of the outside container.  On desktop, the actual size of the slider should be 680 x 380.  As it stands, I have major margins on either side of the slider and really am not sure how to get rid of them.  I'm sure this is easy for most of you but, I can't figure it out.  Secondly, is there an easy way to have the images appear in random order?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks very much

Here is my test page for the slider: https://www.realtimehockey.net/testing.html

I need the slider to fill the entire container much like my current slider here: https://www.realtimehockey.net

```
HTML

     <div id="slidy-container">
  <figure id="slidy">
    <a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iVhs269.png" width="680" height="380" alt="Black-Biscuit Hockey Outfitters" data-caption="Black-Biscuit Hockey Outfitters"></a>
     <a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/cqMgCFa.png?2" width="680" height="380" alt="All Black Hockey Sticks" data-caption="All Black Hockey Sticks" ></a>
     <a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/WhSLIsE.png?1" width="680" height="380" alt="OneHockey Guinness World Record" data-caption="OneHockey Guinness World Record"></a>
     <a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZQ2KecX.png" width="680" height="380" alt="Planet Hockey Camps" data-caption="Planet Hockey Camps"></a>
     <a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/9x1H8wq.png" width="680" height="380" alt="OneHockey Tournaments" data-caption="OneHockey Tournaments"></a>
     <a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1kzo8hS.jpg" width="680" height="380" alt="ScoreStream" data-caption="ScoreStream"></a>
  </figure>
</div>

JS

    var cssSlidy = function(newOptions) {
  var options = (function() {
    var mergedOptions = {},
      defaultOptions = {
        timeOnSlide: 4,
        timeBetweenSlides: 1,
        slidyContainerSelector: '#slidy-container', // name of slider container
        slidySelector: '#slidy', // name of slider
        slidyDirection: 'left', // options: left, right
        fallbackFunction: function() {},
        cssAnimationName: 'slidy',
        captionSource: 'data-caption', // options: data-caption, alt, none
        captionBackground: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
        captionColor: '#fff',
        captionFont: 'anton',
        captionPosition: 'bottom', // options: top, bottom
        captionAppear: 'slide', //  options: slide, perm, fade
        captionSize: '1.3rem', 
        captionPadding: '.6rem'
        };
        for (var option in defaultOptions) mergedOptions[option] = defaultOptions[option];
        for (var option in newOptions) mergedOptions[option] = newOptions[option];
        return mergedOptions;
    })(),
    CS = this;
    CS.animationString = 'animation';
    CS.hasAnimation = false;
    CS.keyframeprefix = '';
    CS.domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O Khtml'.split(' ');
    CS.pfx = '';
    CS.element = document.getElementById(options.slidySelector.replace('#', ''));
    CS.init = (function() {
    // browser supports keyframe animation w/o prefixes
      if (CS.element.style.animationName !== undefined) CS.hasAnimation = true;
        // browser supports keyframe animation w/ prefixes
        if (CS.hasAnimation === false) {
          for (var i = 0; i < CS.domPrefixes.length; i++) {
            if (CS.element.style[CS.domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName'] !== undefined) {
              CS.pfx = domPrefixes[i];
              CS.animationString = pfx + 'Animation';
              CS.keyframeprefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
              CS.hasAnimation = true;
              // determines CSS prefix required for CSS animations
              break;
              }
            }
          }
        if (CS.hasAnimation === true) {
          var images = CS.element.getElementsByTagName("img"),
          L = images.length,
          fig = document.createElement('figure'),
          who, temp;
          while(L) {
                temp = fig.cloneNode(false);
                who = images[--L];
            // wraps all images in the slider with <figure> tags
            if (options.captionSource!=="none")             
                caption = who.getAttribute(options.captionSource);
                who.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, who);
                if (caption !== null) {
                content = document.createElement('figcaption');
                content.innerHTML = caption;
          // places captions in each <figure> element, if required
                }
                temp.appendChild(who);
                if (caption !== null) {
                temp.appendChild(content);
                }
                }
          var figs = CS.element.getElementsByTagName("figure");
          var firstFig = figs[0]; // get the first figure inside the "slidy" element.
          figWrap = firstFig.cloneNode(true); // copy it.
                CS.element.appendChild(figWrap); // add the clone to the end of the images
          var imgCount = images.length, // count the number of images in the slide, including the new cloned element
          totalTime = (options.timeOnSlide + options.timeBetweenSlides) * (imgCount - 1), // calculate the total length of the animation by multiplying the number of _actual_ images by the amount of time for both static display of each image and motion between them
          slideRatio = (options.timeOnSlide / totalTime) * 100, // determine the percentage of time an induvidual image is held static during the animation
          moveRatio = (options.timeBetweenSlides / totalTime) * 100, // determine the percentage of time for an individual movement
          basePercentage = 100 / imgCount, // work out how wide each image should be in the slidy, as a percentage.
          position = 0, // set the initial position of the slidy element
          css = document.createElement("style"); // start marking a new style sheet
          // creating css style tag
          css.type = "text/css";
          css.id = options.slidySelector.replace('#', '') + "-css";
          css.innerHTML += options.slidyContainerSelector + " { overflow: hidden; }\n";
          css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " { text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 0; position: relative; width: " + (imgCount * 100) + "%;  }\n"; // set the width for the inner slider container
          css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " figure { float: left; margin: 0; position: relative; display: inline-block; width: " + basePercentage + "%; height: auto; }\n"; // set the width and size pf the inner <figure> elements
          css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " figure img { width: 100%; }\n";
          css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " figure figcaption { position: absolute; width: 100%; background-color: " + options.captionBackground + "; color: " + options.captionColor + "; font-family: " + options.captionFont + ";";

          var captions = document.getElementsByTagName("figcaption");
          var captionHeight = captions[0].offsetHeight*2 +  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(captions[0]).fontSize, 10);
          if (options.captionPosition == "top") {
            switch (options.captions) {
                case 'fade':
                    css.innerHTML += " top: 0; opacity: 0;";
                    break;
                case 'slide': 
                    css.innerHTML += " top: -"+captionHeight+"px; ";
                    break;
                default: 
                    css.innerHTML += " top: 0;";
                }
            } else {
               switch (options.captionAppear) {
                case 'fade':
                    css.innerHTML += " bottom: 0; opacity: 0;";
                    break;
                case 'slide': 
                    css.innerHTML += " bottom: -"+captionHeight+"px; ";
                    break;
                default: 
                    css.innerHTML += " bottom: 0;";
                }
            }
            css.innerHTML += " font-size: " + options.captionSize +  "; padding: " + options.captionPadding + "; " + keyframeprefix + "transition: .5s; }\n";
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + ":hover figure figcaption { opacity: 1; ";
            if (options.captionPosition == "top") { css.innerHTML += " top: 0px;"; }
            else { css.innerHTML += " bottom: 0px;"; }
            css.innerHTML += " }\n";
            css.innerHTML += "@" + keyframeprefix + "keyframes " + options.cssAnimationName + " {\n";
     if (options.slidyDirection == "right") {
         for (i = imgCount - 1; i > 0; i--) { // 
                position += slideRatio; // make the keyframe the position of the image
                css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + (i * 100) + "%; }\n";
                position += moveRatio; // make the postion for the _next_ slide
                css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + ((i - 1) * 100) + "%; }\n";
}
     } else {  // the slider is moving to the left    
            for (i = 0; i < (imgCount - 1); i++) { // 
                position += slideRatio; // make the keyframe the position of the image
                css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + (i * 100) + "%; }\n";
                position += moveRatio; // make the postion for the _next_ slide
                css.innerHTML += position + "% { left: -" + ((i + 1) * 100) + "%; }\n";
            }
         }
       css.innerHTML += "}\n";
            css.innerHTML += options.slidySelector + " { ";
           if (options.slidyDirection == "right") { css.innerHTML += "left: " + imgCount*100+"%" }
           else { css.innerHTML += "left: 0%; " }

           css.innerHTML += keyframeprefix + "transform: translate3d(0,0,0); " + keyframeprefix + "animation: " + totalTime + "s " + options.cssAnimationName + " infinite; }\n"; // call on the completed keyframe animation sequence
            // place css style tag
            if (options.cssLocation !== undefined) options.cssLocation.appendChild(css);
            else document.body.appendChild(css);
        } else {
            // fallback function
            options.fallbackFunction();
        }
    })();
}
cssSlidy();

CSS

    body {
  background: #ffffff;
}
#slidy-container { 
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: #slidy-container { width: 100%}

Comment: Got it.  Worked. Thanks @Gerardo BLANCO Any idea with showing the slide in random order?  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: I would probably append the `a` elements to the `figure` via a random js function onload